# Função contar comentários e outro programa por linha de comando em C

Tags: c

Estou com dificuldades de saber como desenvolver uma função que através de linha de comando irá contar e exibir a quantidade de linhas comentadas de outro programa em .c, por exemplo:

Contador ProgramaExemplo.c -c

O argumento -c irá chamar executar a função para contar a linha, qualquer outro argumento informará inválido.

No entanto é necessário que se faça em arquivos diferentes o que já fiz foi isso. Essa função tem outros argumentos, mas o importante é apenas o de contagem de linhas (essa função está assim pq foi a "recomendada" no trabalho).

Os comentários que podem ser contados tem que ser o de uma linha // ou bloco /* */ os que estiverem depois de alguma outra ação não precisa ser contado, por exemplo:

// imprime ola  <-- Essa conta

printf ("ola mundo"); // isso é um olá mundo  <<-- esse não precisa contar

/* ola mundo */ <-- Essa conta

Arquivo: **LibCodeCount.c**

```
/* ****************************************************
 * Função para contar Quantidade de linhas comentadas *
 * de um arquivo .c lido                              *
 ******************************************************/
#include <stdio.h>
#include "LibCodeCount.h"

void ccRun(char* file, int* nLines, int* nLinesComent, int* nLinesEmpty, int noComment, int silent)
{

}
```

Arquivo **LibCodeCount.h**

```
/* ********************************************
 * Cabeçalho Header da função LibCodeCount.c  *
 ******************************************** */

void ccRun(char* file, int* nLines, int* nLinesComent, int* nLinesEmpty, int noComment, int silent);
```

Arquivo **MainCodeCount.c**

```
/* *********************************************************
 * Função Main que irá executar o programa para a contagem *
 * de linhas comentadas de outro arquivo em C              *
 ***********************************************************/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "LibCodeCount.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

}
```

Depois da função certa, ai vou gerar um .exe que quando executar no DoS junto com argumento e arquivo mostrará a quantidade de linhas comentadas.

Eu já busquei ler sobre Argc e Argv achei um pouco confuso, mas gostaria de um apoio mais avançado mesmo.

Desde já agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: Me parece que você precisa dividir o problema em partes menores, e se for o caso ir perguntando sobre os problemas específicos que for encontrando. Por exemplo, comece aprendendo a (ou perguntando sobre) ler os argumentos passados ao executável; depois, como ler um arquivo do disco e processar por linha, e por aí vai. Sua pergunta atual pede para alguém resolver a tarefa toda pra você.

Comment: Eu postei a pergunta assim acreditando que pudesse ajudar a pessoa a responder o meu problema, pode até parecer que eu quero a tarefa toda, mas queria mesmo entender os passos para apenas criar a função de ler linhas comentadas.

Answer (score 2):

Para um programa com necessidades reduzidas como o teu, nao precisas de complicar.

Os argumentos da funcao `main()` (o `argc` e o `argv`) indicam respectivamente quantos e quais foram esses argumentos.

Caso um programa seja executado sem argumentos, o valor de `argc` sera `1`.
Caso um programa seja executado com 1 argumento, o valor de `argc` sera `2`.
Caso um programa seja executado com 2 argumentos, o valor de `argc` sera `3`.
etc, etc ...

Portanto o teu programa pode comecar assim

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Formato de chamada invalido.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    // ...
    return 0;
}
```

Em vez do `// ...` deves verificar se um dos parametros e `-c` e assumir que o outro e o nome dum ficheiro.

Tenta abrir o ficheiro, se der erro informa o utilizador de ficheiro invalido, se nao der erro, conta os comentarios.